# is it possible to render a function inside insertadjacentHTML parameter?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, insertadjacenthtml

i am trying to reuse a function that will render contents anywhere i use it outside of it's birthplace.
i have this code which fetches data from API

```
const showData = async function(){
   try{
       const res = await fetch(url);
       const data = await res.json();
       
       const results = data.results;
       
       const markup = results.map(elements =>{
             (.......)
         return `...html elements..`
       }).join('');

  }
  catch(error){
    console.log(error)
  }

}
```

thing is i wanna reuse this `makrup` variable in some other places as well.
i tried to wrap this markup inside a function..

```
function generateMarkup(){
      const results....and so on until the html with return statement
  }
  generateMarkup();
```

as it tried to render it like this..

```
display.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin',generateMarkup);
```

as you guessed,it did not work,whether i close the function with parenthesis or not.

i also tried to return markup and html elements putting it inside an array.did not work either.
or is there any other way u can reuse this code in some other places?
can you plz help?

Comment: `generateMarkup().then(result=>display.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin',result);` but your async function needs to actually `return markup`.

Comment: either way it is not working, first one,can not read property of undefined and second one, after returning markup,says "genereateMarkup().then.." is not a function. :S